# Initial Layer Line width in PrusaSlicer

Tags: ultimaker-cura, prusaslicer

In Cura, there is a setting called: `Initial Layer Line Width`. What is its equivalent in PrusaSlicer?

Answer (score 5):

If you look in **Print Settings** > **Advanced** tab, you will find `First Layer` under **Extrusion Width**.

However, do not assume that every option in Cura will have an equivalent setting in other slicers.